# How to upload a file to server and create a public URL from Java program?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, webserver, couchbase

I need to fetch files from a database (couchbase) and then I've to send that file to server and then I need to create a url to download that file.

Please tell me, I am not understanding where to start.

So my doubt is how to send a file to web server which I read from DB and how to generate download link URL. I am using Spring with webservices.

Comment: Do you know about wevservices, RESTful services etc.. ?

Comment: I did it, By using FTP and apache http client as a webserver, Thank you for your reply guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpRequest object to upload file to web server.

You don't want  to create a custom url to download. Just create a common url and pass file name or file id as parameter, write a class to download it manually. 
`HttpURLConnection` enables to create a connection to server.